# Probit model specification

Tags: probit, definition

im writing a paper that involves using a probit regression, would this be a correct summary of what a probt model is and how it works?:

"the probit specification is a binary-dependent model that takes a transformation of the vector of observable characteristics according to the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution"

is this a technically correct definition? thanks

Comment: It's vague and incomplete, but not overtly incorrect.  You might want to tailor your summary to the audience.  Whom do you have in mind?

Comment: its for my undergraduate dissertation, i just need a succinct definition so it doesnt take up too many words. i run a probit model and the take margins to work out effect of different variables on the probability of an event occurring

Comment: Maybe describe it as a subset of generalized linear models. But is there a specific reason you are using probit over logit link (logistic regression)?

Comment: I am using a probit (over a logit) model as a necessary precursor to a later heckman test.    the probit test is performed on the binary variable "sale" and a vector of characteristics. by then taking margins, i present the average marginal effect of the variables on the dependent variable, which are interpreted as the effect on the probability of an item selling.